# how to escape asterisk in regex using java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following pattern:

```
<* ab: cdef *>
<************>
abc: <starting now>
```

I need to escape the lines that have <* pattern.

I have used `\\*` and `\\\\*` to escape the \ and the *. But this doesn't work

How do I escape the * in regex using Java?

I cannot escape the lines have < alone as the other lines will be skipped too.

I have used the code below:

```
if(str.matches("<\\*.*")) {
                //Do nothing.
}
```

str is initialized by using the BufferedReader as follows:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String str = br.readLine();
```

Comment: Please show us the code. [`\\*` is enough](http://ideone.com/4e2Rb4) to escape the asterisk in a regex pattern.

Comment: i have made the edits. the formatting was just wrong. sorry 'bout that!

Comment: so basically you want to match the strings which start with `<*`

Comment: can you share how `str` is initialized?

Comment: yes, that's what i want.

Comment: if `str = "<* ab: cdef *>"` the pattern already does match

Comment: Use `if (str.trim().startsWith("<*"))` to check if a string starts with some known characters, there is no need in regex.

Comment: I guess `br.readLine()` is called iteratively, for each new line, right?

Comment: please, also state what you actually get, since what you have posted seems to work. Right now, it's not clear what exactly the problem is, and the question might be closed...

Comment: If it matches, you do nothing. But then what? Is your code in an `else` clause? Because if it is not, you just pass through the `if` clause and execute whatever is below. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31741608/1734119) is interesting because it can protect you agains this kind of case.

Comment: Just to make things easier to read, if you want to do things only when line does not match, you may rewrite your test `if (!str.matches("<\\*.*")) { /* NOW we do something */ }`.

Answer (score 4):

To escape `*` in regex you need double backslash: `\\*` because `*` is a special character in regex.

You could also try with this (if you expect this pattern to be present at the beginning of the line, like in your examples):

```
if (str.trim().startsWith("<*")) {
    //your code
}
```

consequently, if you expect the pattern to appear anywhere in the string, you could use:

```
if (str.contains("<*")) {
    //your code
}
```

And I am pretty sure you don't need regex for these simple cases.

Comment: If it is a solution, I guess the question should be closed. There must be some typo on the user's end.

Answer (score 3):

You should also match the white spaces before the '<' character, like

```
if(str.trim().matches("<\\*.*")) {
            //Do nothing.
}
```

or `str.matches("\\s*<\\*.*")`.

You should also read the next line iteratively, like:

```
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) { 

    if(str.trim().matches("<\\*.*")) {
            //Do nothing.
    } else {
            //else do something...
    }
}
```

(which is not clear from the OP)

Comment: You should make the `else` code instead of comment: it could be misleading because it implies that you're in an `else` once you passed the `if`. This would work only if the `if` contained a `continue`. However, this kind of control flow can make code harder to read and that is when [fantaghirocco's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31741608/1734119) comes in handy along your own.

Comment: @Chop thanks, I updated my answer with your constructive comment

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that pattern is considered not matched because the debugger cannot stop inside an empty `if` block - *do nothing* is always a bad practice: *do something* instead!

Your pattern already matches the case which follows:

```
String str = "<* ab: cdef *>";
if(str.matches("<\\*.*")) {
    //do something
    System.out.println("matches");
}
```

The above prints **matches**.

If your wish is not to consider the extra leading spaces, you can use this pattern `" *<\\*.*"` which matches zero or more leading blank characters.

Comment: I guess this should be a comment, as it does not provide a solution to the actual problem of the OP.

Comment: @vefthym not exactly: maybe the OP considers that pattern does not match because the debugger cannot stops inside an empty `if` block